# Why is my EC2 instance detroyed and created on every apply?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform to manage my infrastructure in AWS, I have used Terraform to launch one bastion instance.

My issue is that every time I do a `terraform plan`, Terraform tells me that it would be destroy and recreate that bastion instance and `terraform apply` does it.

Here is my code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  ami = var.ami_id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = var.key_name
  monitoring = false
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.`bastion_sg`.id]
  subnet_id = var.subnet_id_private
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.instance_profile.name
  user_data = data.template_file.script.rendered

   tags = merge(
    {
      "Name" = local.name_prefix
    },
    var.default_tags,
  )

  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"
    volume_size = 8
    volume_type = "gp2"
    delete_on_termination = true

  }
  
}
```

Here is `terrafrom plan` output:

```
  # module.bastion.aws_instance.bastion must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
      ~ arn                          = "arn:aws:ec2:xx-xxxx-x:xxxxx:instance/i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -> (known after apply)
      ~ associate_public_ip_address  = false -> (known after apply)
      ~ availability_zone            = "xx-xxxx-xx" -> (known after apply)
      ~ cpu_core_count               = 1 -> (known after apply)
      ~ cpu_threads_per_core         = 1 -> (known after apply)
      - disable_api_termination      = false -> null
      - ebs_optimized                = false -> null
      - hibernation                  = false -> null
      + host_id                      = (known after apply)
      ~ id                           = "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -> (known after apply)
      ~ instance_state               = "running" -> (known after apply)
      ~ ipv6_address_count           = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ ipv6_addresses               = [] -> (known after apply)
      + outpost_arn                  = (known after apply)
      + password_data                = (known after apply)
      + placement_group              = (known after apply)
      ~ primary_network_interface_id = "eni-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_dns                  = "ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.compute.internal" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_ip                   = "xx.xxx.x.xx" -> (known after apply)
      + public_dns                   = (known after apply)
      + public_ip                    = (known after apply)
      ~ secondary_private_ips        = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ security_groups              = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ tenancy                      = "default" -> (known after apply)
        # (10 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - credit_specification {
          - cpu_credits = "standard" -> null
        }

      + ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
          + delete_on_termination = true
          + device_name           = "/dev/sda1"
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + throughput            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = 8
          + volume_type           = "gp2"
        }
      - ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
          - delete_on_termination = true -> null
          - device_name           = "/dev/sda1" -> null
          - encrypted             = false -> null
          - iops                  = 100 -> null
          - snapshot_id           = "snap-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -> null
          - tags                  = {} -> null
          - throughput            = 0 -> null
          - volume_id             = "vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -> null
          - volume_size           = 8 -> null
          - volume_type           = "gp2" -> null
        }

      ~ enclave_options {
          ~ enabled = false -> (known after apply)
        }

      + ephemeral_block_device {
          + device_name  = (known after apply)
          + no_device    = (known after apply)
          + virtual_name = (known after apply)
        }

      ~ metadata_options {
          ~ http_endpoint               = "enabled" -> (known after apply)
          ~ http_put_response_hop_limit = 1 -> (known after apply)
          ~ http_tokens                 = "optional" -> (known after apply)
        }

      + network_interface {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_index          = (known after apply)
          + network_interface_id  = (known after apply)
        }

      ~ root_block_device {
          ~ delete_on_termination = true -> (known after apply)
          ~ device_name           = "/dev/sda1" -> (known after apply)
          ~ encrypted             = false -> (known after apply)
          ~ iops                  = 100 -> (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          ~ tags                  = {} -> (known after apply)
          ~ throughput            = 0 -> (known after apply)
          ~ volume_id             = "vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -> (known after apply)
          ~ volume_size           = 8 -> (known after apply)
          ~ volume_type           = "gp2" -> (known after apply)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

So it is the EBS volume that is causing the replacement.

The most likely cause is that it hasn't been able to attach to `/dev/sda1` so when Terraform looks in the plan it sees its disk is not on sda1 and decides it needs to replace the instance.

You would need to confirm this when the instance is running to see where your volume has been attached to (this can be on the instance or in the console).

It is likely that the root volume has been attached to sda1 pushing yours elsewhere.

If this is the case then you would need to change the mount point of this volume OR if you intend this to be the root volume then use `root_block_device`